# Playing Arpeggios

Tags: javascript, html, css, howler.js

I am working on incorporating arpeggios into the chord library but I am having trouble doing that. I believe the change that needs to happen is in the portion of the displayAndPlayChordIntervals where let chordIntervals unites the notes into playing those notes as one chord. When I try to separate them it makes no changes and I am not sure on how to go with the code to have the chord buttons play as an arpeggio rather than a chord.
Is the change to the displayAndPlayChord idea correct or should I be looking at another portion of the code?

```js
//In order to run in terminal insert the following code to activate localhost: npx parcel src/index.html
import {transpose, note } from '@tonaljs/tonal';
import { chord } from '@tonaljs/chord';
import { entries } from '@tonaljs/chord-type';
import { Howler, howl } from 'howler';

const sound = new Howl({
    src: ['assets/pianosprite.mp3'],
    onload() {
        console.log('Sound file has been loaded. Do something here!');
        soundEngine.init();
    },
    onloaderror(e, msg) {
        console.log('Error', e, msg);
    }
});

const startNotes = ['C', 'C#', 'Db', 'D', 'D#', 'Eb', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'Gb', 'G', 'G#', 'Ab', 'A', 'A#', 'Bb', 'B']; 

const startNoteSelector = document.querySelector('#start-note');
const octaveSelector = document.querySelector('#octave');

const buttons = document.querySelector(".buttons");

const intervalsInChord = document.querySelector('.intervals-in-chord');
const notesInChord = document.querySelector('.notes-in-chord');

let selectedStartNote = 'C';
let selectedOctave = '1';
let selectedChord;

const app = {
    init() {
        this.setupStartNotes();
        this.setupOctaves();
        this.setupButtons();
        this.setupEventListeners();
    },
    setupStartNotes() {
        startNotes.forEach(noteName => {
            let noteNameOption = this.createElement('option', noteName);
            startNoteSelector.appendChild(noteNameOption);
        });
    },
    setupOctaves() {
        for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            let octaveNumber = this.createElement('option', i);
            octaveSelector.appendChild(octaveNumber);
        }
    },
    setupButtons() {
        const chordNames = ["maj7", "m7", "dim7", "maj7#5"];
        chordNames.forEach(chordName => {
          let chordButton = this.createElement('button', chordName);
          buttons.appendChild(chordButton);
        });
      },
    setupEventListeners() {
        startNoteSelector.addEventListener('change', () => {
            selectedStartNote = startNoteSelector.value;
        });
        octaveSelector.addEventListener('change', () => {
            selectedOctave = octaveSelector.value;
        });
        buttons.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            if (event.target.classList.contains('buttons')) {
                return;
            }
            selectedChord = event.target.innerText;
            this.displayAndPlayChord(selectedChord, event,);
        });
    },
    displayAndPlayChord(selectedChord, event) {
        let chordIntervals = chord(selectedChord).intervals;
        intervalsInChord.innerText = chordIntervals.join(' - ');
        
        const startNoteWithOctave = selectedStartNote + selectedOctave;
        let chordNotes = chordIntervals.map(val => {
            return transpose(startNoteWithOctave, val);
        });
        notesInChord.innerText = chordNotes.join(' - ');
        soundEngine.play(chordNotes, event);
    },
    createElement(elementName, content) {
        let element = document.createElement(elementName);
        element.innerHTML = content;
        return element;
    }
}

const soundEngine = {
    init() {
        const lengthOfNote = 2400;
        let timeIndex = 0;
        for (let i = 24; i <= 96; i++) {
            sound['_sprite'][i] = [timeIndex, lengthOfNote];
            timeIndex += lengthOfNote;
        }
        
    },


    
    play(soundSequence, event) {
        //const buttons =
        //document.querySelector(".buttons");

        const chordNameTable = {
        "maj7": "major seventh",
        "m7": "minor seventh",
        "dim7": "diminished seventh",
        "maj7#5": "Augmented seventh"
    
          }

          buttons.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            
          })
          function textToSpeech(message, chord) {
            const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            speech.lang = "en-US";
            speech.text = message;
            speech.volume = 1;
            speech.rate = 1;
            speech.pitch = 1;
            window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
            // When speaking has finished
            speech.onend = function() {
              playChord(chord);
            }
          }
          function playChord(chord) {
            // Wait a second (1000 miliseconds) before playing the chord
            setTimeout(() => {
                const chordMidiNumbers = soundSequence.map(noteName => {
                    return note(noteName).midi;
                });
                sound.volume(0.05);
                chordMidiNumbers.forEach(noteMidiNumber => {
                    
                    sound.play(noteMidiNumber.toString());
                });
              console.log("Chord to be played", chord);
            }, 500);
          }
          const sayThis = chordNameTable[event.target.textContent];
            textToSpeech(sayThis, event.target.textContent);
    }
}


app.init();

const allChordNames = entries()
chordEntries.map(entry => {
    return entry.aliases[0];
})
console.log(Array.isArray (allChordNames));
```